# If application stop, Then Notification not display in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating simple application for Notification. It is showing notification properly But my main question is,

Why Notification not display when application stop? Any special settings for that. Please help me.

Application stop from: 
1. Setting/application/manage application 
2. selecting application
3. force stop

this way i stop my application
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "application stop"?

Comment: you need to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for that...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here...

Comment: I set time for notification using my app, notification show correct when this app is running in background. If we force stop this app then this notification not display at that selected time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go for Service development for notification for your android application. You need to just start the service in your android application then even though your app stops, your notification will not affect. It will continuous in running mode at background.

Here are two examples from you can learn easily:

[Android Service example-1](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/simple-example-of-service-in-android.html)

[Android Service example-2](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/basic-android-background-service.html)

Comment: if you force stop the application service will no longer be running.

Comment: @Rasel : Yes, After force stop, Service also stop. Is not use for me. Any other solution for that.

Comment: User force stops the application.That means he doesn't want anything anymore of this application.If needed again he will launch the application for sure.so yes, here is a solution....You do nothing.

Comment: Hi all, My problem solved with Broadcast Receiver. I manage my service with Broadcast Receiver... Thank you for all reply.